# How to pass multiple date1 i.e(10/12/2016) , date2 i.e(23/12/2016) to url in django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am trying to pass starting_date i.e(10/12/2016) ,report_to_date i.e(23/12/2016)

```
starting_date = '31/12/2015'
report_to_date = '31/12/2016'  
<a class ="btn btn-success" href="/downloadpdf/"+starting_date+"/"+report_to_date+"/">Download</a>
```

below url not working -

```
url(r'^/downloadpdf/(?P<starting_date>[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+)/(?P<report_to_date>[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+)/$', views.report, name='report'),
```

I need the date i.e '31/12/2015' and i.e '31/12/2016' format/date object  to my view function :

```
def report(request,starting_date,report_to_date):
        starting_date = parse('starting_date')
        report_to_date = parse('report_to_date')
```

this is not working. Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this is not working` In what way does it not work? What does or doesn't it do and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I want to pass the multiple date to the django url. But its not happening when i am passing date string ('31/12/2015').

Comment: _what_ is not happening? are `starting_date` and `report_to_date` empty strings?

Comment: url getting something/31/12/2015 . I mean i want to pass date object to the url.

Comment: try separating the individual parts of the date with another character, like `-`, so the slashes `/` in the date-string don't interfere with the path separators `/`

Comment: i tried like 31-12-2015 but don't know its also not working.

Comment: Is it possible to send date object ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Felk said in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195446/how-to-pass-multiple-date1-i-e10-12-2016-date2-i-e23-12-2016-to-url-in-dja#comment69590924_41195446) you need to change date format to dd-mm-YYYY to avoid problems with readability.

For that you need to change urlpattern to accept `-` and numbers:

```
url(r'^downloadpdf/(?P<starting_date>[0-9-]+)/(?P<report_to_date>[0-9-]+)$', views.report, name='report')
```

Now you can use this pattern inside template like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'report' starting_date='17-12-2016' report_to_date='17-12-2016' %}">date</a>
```

To parse date values inside view you can use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function:

```
import datetime
...
def report(request, starting_date, report_to_date):
    starting_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(starting_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
    report_to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(report_to_date, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
```

Comment: Thanks #neverwalkaloner